# I am trying to draw a rectangle using "*"

Tags: java

When I am running this program in eclipse I am getting the output that shows a rectangle with 5 stars in a column and 5 stars in a row. It should be 5 stars in a column and 2 stars as row. What's wrong with my code?

```
public class printing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      printStars(5);
//      printStars(3);
//      printStars(9);
//      printStars(4);
//      printSqare(4);
        printRectangle(5,2);

    }
    private static void printStars(int amount) {
         int i = 0;
            while ( i < amount ) {
                System.out.print("*");
                i++;
         }
            System.out.println("\n");
    }

//  private static void printSqare(int sidesize){
//      int c= 0;
//      while (c < sidesize){
//          printStars(sidesize);
//          c++;
//      }
//      System.out.println("\n");
//  } 



private static void printRectangle(int width, int height) {

    int num1=0;
    for (int num2=1; num2<height; num2++){
        while (num1 < width ){
        printStars(width);
        num1++;
            }   
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write expected output??

Comment: the expected output is clear

Answer (score 4):

Your commented `printSquare` method is actually good, you can reuse the algorithm for `printRectangle` !
You need only one loop here, so

```
private static void printRectangle(int width, int height) {
    int num1=0;
    while (num1 < height ){
        printStars(width);
        num1++;      
    }       
}
```

or

```
private static void printRectangle(int width, int height) {
    for (int num1 = 0; num1 < height; num1++ ){
        printStars(width);     
    }       
}
```

In you current code, you enter in the `for` loop, and then call `printStars` in your `while` loop. However, `while` loops 5 times instead of 2, because of the condition `num1 < width` (instead `num1 < height`). Then, `for` loops a second time and do nothing (because `num1` is greater than `width`).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your printRectangle method like

```
private static void printRectangle(int width, int height) {

    for (int num2 = 0; num2 < height; num2++) {
            printStars(width);
    }
}
```

I read your question as having 5*2 rectangle. Not sure if its correct interpretation though.

Comment: `printStars` already loops and prints a row of stars, so your second loop is useless (or don't use this function). Moreover, it should be `num2 < height` and `num1 < width` (actually your algorithm prints a 2*5 rectangle)... -1 until correction ;)

Comment: Yes you are correct about the useless loop. Actually I did not posted the full code, but I have switched the call printRectangle(2,5). This height and width is very confusing to deal. So I thought height = rows and width = columns. So 5 stars in column means 5 rows ...